# Do we need nodejs and express for ionic-angular-firebase project?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, express, ionic4

If authentication is done by firebase, stores data and many more features. Then do we need nodejs and express for angular firebase project or in angluar ionic firebase project ?
.As angular converts the code to html, css and js, which causes data threat from hackers. But we do use js file for nodejs. so how we can protect it.

Comment: In angular u already use nodejs.. Angular is installed using nodejs

Comment: But not express. Express is only used as middleware if you are creating API calls to handle data.  Express is not needed if you are using firebase.